# Sharepoint 2010 List and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

as a newbie to Sharepoint.... I have created a simple list with several columns in Sharepoint 2010.

I now want to add a button on the List that I can programmatically add some onClick events to do the following:

- get a handle on some of the columns in the list;
- Distribute an email automatically based on the content of some of the columns

I am looking at using c# via Visual Studio 2010 for all the programmatic aspect of this development.

Is it possible to export the xml from Sharepoint 2010 then import into Visual Studio 2010 so that I can use the list I created as my starting point for the coding work?  If so, how do I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to setup Visual Studio to work with Sharepoint.
Install it on a server that has Sharepoint 2010 running.

You can then create a webpart that incorporates the list (or a view on it) and add the button to that list.

But I imagine that you'll want to work on a specific row.  So what you want is a Custom Action on that list (Visual Studio has a template for that: Add -> New Item -> Custom Action).
The Custom Action will create a new item in the Edit Control Block (the context menu that appears for every item in the list).

I prefer to create the ECB (Edit Control Block) menu items using JavaScript.  In the page load I inject a jSon string that has additional information about each of the rows, and a JavaScript function then is called by the builtin SharePoint javaScript function that creates the ECB.

The JavaScript function you'll have to create is Custom_AddListMenuItems .

In that function you'll call CAMOpt to create menu items.  If you want SharePoint to create the built-in menu items (and Custom Actions you created), set the return value of the Custom_AddListMenuItems function to true. (And fals if you don't want to see the built in ECB menu items and any Custom Actions you created)

You can start here:[Jan Tielens Blogging's](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/09/03/customizing-the-sharepoint-ecb-with-javascript-part-1.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I just clarify something here.   "You can then create a webpart that incorporates the list (or a view on it) and add the button to that list."  Does that mean that I can design my List 100% in Sharepoint and then add the list to the webpart via Visual Studio?  I have Visual Studio up and running so just need to understand how to link the webpart added in VS 2010 to the List created in Sharepoint?

Comment: You can reference any SharePoint list and add it to a WebPart. It's the ListViewWebPart you need.    You have to get an instance of the list (SPList instance = web.Lists[ListName];), get a view of it and assign its HTMLShcemaXml property to the webPart's ListViewXml property.